# How to replace variables in R based on multiple conditions?

Tags: r

I have a column with a list of ages, and I'm trying to separate the ages into three separate values: young, middle aged, and senior.

If I do a nested ifelse, as in:

```
df$age <- ifelse(df$age <= 40, "young",
   ifelse((df$age > 40) & (df$age < 65), "middle",
      ifelse(df$age >= 65, "senior, "")))
```

...then all of the values in the column are replaced with "young" and "middle," with no "senior."

If I replace the values individually by assignment, as in:

```
df$age[df$age <= 40] <- "young"
df$age[df$age > 40 & df$age < 65] <- "middle"
df$age[df$age >= 65] <- "senior"
```

...then all of the values in the column are replaced with "senior."

It seems that once the integers in the column are replaced with the first set of characters, it changes the entire column to the character class. I'm not sure if that's what's causing the problem, so I've tried putting as.integer around the functions, but the results are the same.

How do I fix this so that the variables in my column are all properly labeled?

Comment: Try `df$age <- ifelse(df$age <= 40, "young",
   ifelse(df$age > 40 & df$age < 65, "middle", "senior"))`

Comment: I actually tried that as well and I had the same problem, unfortunately.

Comment: Then provide a sample of your data. You can also have a look into `case_when` of `dplyr`, e.g. something like `library(dplyr) df <- df %>% mutate(age = case_when(age <= 40 ~ 'young', age >= 65 ~ 'senior', TRUE ~ 'middle'))`, provided you don't have `NA`s

Comment: That seems to have done the trick, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways both with base R only.

Sample data:

```
set.seed(1234)    # Make the results reproducible
age <- sample(10:100, 10)
```

Now categorize the numbers.

```
i <- findInterval(age, c(0, 40, 65, Inf))
category <- c("young", "middle", "senior")[i]
data.frame(age, category)
```

Another way.

```
category2 <- cut(age, breaks = c(0, 40, 65, Inf), labels = c("young", "middle", "senior"))
data.frame(age, category2)
#   age category2
#1   37     young
#2   89    senior
#3   31     young
#4   18     young
#5   14     young
#6   47    middle
#7   25     young
#8   13     young
#9   79    senior
#10  88    senior
```

Comment: Might be worth warning that `cut` and `findInterval` give slightly different results at the boundaries - check `data.frame(age, category, category2)`

Answer (score 0):

When you do your first replacement you are coercing column `df$age` to `character`. Afterwards the operators `<` and `>` work differently. Try creating a new column `age2` instead:

```
df$age2 <- NA_character_
df$age2 <- ifelse(df$age <= 40, "young",
   ifelse((df$age > 40) & (df$age < 65), "middle",
      ifelse(df$age >= 65, "senior, "")))
```